# How to permanently activate Efficiency Mode to all processes in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

How to permanently activate Efficiency Mode to all processes and applications in Windows 11?

My Windows specification is:

```
Edition == Windows 11 Home Single Language 
Version == 22H2 
Installed on == ‎02/‎12/‎2022 
OS build == 22621.2715 
Experience == Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22677.1000.0
```

In Task Manager, we can see 'Efficiency Mode' for Apps, Background processes, Windows processes in Processes tab.

If we want to activate it, we need to choose individual Apps/Background processes/Windows processes and then activate it.

So, if 100 things we need to repeat it 100 times.

Is there any way to activate 'Efficiency Mode' for all Apps, Background processes, Windows processes permanently by following ways:

- By some command which need to add in command prompt or PowerShell?
- Or by script which can run in PowerShell?
- Or by some trick which use in windows settings/advance settings/registry entries etc?
- Or by some third party app?

Need Help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found would be your 4th point: Some third party app.

**Tool**: Process Lasso by Bitsum

Go to *Options/Cpu/Efficiency modes...*
There, activate efficiency mode and make a rule for "*".
It is a wildcard character acting as placeholder, so more specific filters are possible too.

**Pro**: every new/current process (except System invoked) gets changed to E-mode

**Con**: the process of changing takes time (just a little) itself so it'd be great if Microsoft would make a selection-by-Process-Type possible... and permanent.

Result for my intel 13700H laptop CPU which I cannot undervolt:

- passively cooled & internal Graphics:
  35-40°C at idle; 42-47°C during browsing/videos/writing&building small code;
- minimum active cooling: avrg -5°C; 33-36°C at idle; 36-42°C during browsing/videos/writing&building small code;

During games with ext. Gfx the PowerPlan looks different and the temps too...

Comment: Is this a copy/paste from somewhere? If so, don't do this. Restate information found elsewhere, and provide a link for attribution.

Comment: No it is not a copy paste - I tried it out on my machine and kept it in the described states for some minutes for the temps to settle.

Comment: However, if you found a similar post/discussion somewhere else, please post the link so I can refer to it.
The way I got to the tool was through another one of their programs which was simpler but did not work out for me.

Comment: The "Point 4: Process..." line at the beginning looked like a copy/paste, but I see now you're referring to the 4th of their sub-questions.

Comment: np m8, I see what you mean. I'll try to formulate it better. Thx for noticing tough

Answer (score 0):

@JustSomeGuy

You totally rock! I was on several Teams meetings and I could not do anything. I downloaded the Lasso application, and this helped a lot. My computer processes for Chrome and Micorosft Teams was causing my computer to act SUPER SLOW, slower than a turle. After I found this forum, and added the below rules and so far everything is working fine.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isOrh.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).